# Creating a new key with values within a sub dictionary of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, data-structures

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dictionary = {'Kyle': {'benz':2, 'ford':1, 'bmw':5, 'gmc':6, 'subaru':3}
              'Jim': {'benz':5, 'ford':9, 'bmw':3, 'gmc':1, 'subaru':2}
              'Tom': {'benz':3, 'ford':4, 'bmw':8, 'gmc':2, 'subaru':10}
              'Eric: {'benz':6, 'ford':7, 'bmw':9, 'gmc':5, 'subaru':3}
             }
```

My objective is to create a new key called: 'german_cars'

Which takes the sum of the keys 'bmw' and 'benz'.

I want to have the newly created key 'german_cars' within `my_dictionary` like this:

```
my_dictionary = {'Kyle': {'benz':2, 'ford':1, 'bmw':5, 'gmc':6, 'subaru':3, 'german_cars':7}
              'Jim': {'benz':5, 'ford':9, 'bmw':3, 'gmc':1, 'subaru':2, 'german_cars':8}
              'Tom': {'benz':3, 'ford':4, 'bmw':8, 'gmc':2, 'subaru':10, 'german_cars':11}
              'Eric: {'benz':6, 'ford':7, 'bmw':9, 'gmc':5, 'subaru':3, 'german_cars':15}
             }
```

I would like to know an automated way of doing this using for loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {'Kyle': {'benz':2, 'ford':1, 'bmw':5, 'gmc':6, 'subaru':3},
              'Jim': {'benz':5, 'ford':9, 'bmw':3, 'gmc':1, 'subaru':2},
              'Tom': {'benz':3, 'ford':4, 'bmw':8, 'gmc':2, 'subaru':10},
              'Eric': {'benz':6, 'ford':7, 'bmw':9, 'gmc':5, 'subaru':3}
             }
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    v['german_cars'] = v['bmw']+v['benz']
```

you can also dictionary comprehensions like this

```
{k:v.update({'german_cars':v['bmw']+v['benz']}) for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

both yield the same result.

```
print my_dict
```

results in

```
{'Eric': {'benz': 6,
          'bmw': 9,
          'ford': 7,
          'german_cars': 15,
          'gmc': 5,
          'subaru': 3},
 'Jim': {'benz': 5,
         'bmw': 3,
         'ford': 9,
         'german_cars': 8,
         'gmc': 1,
         'subaru': 2},
 'Kyle': {'benz': 2,
          'bmw': 5,
          'ford': 1,
          'german_cars': 7,
          'gmc': 6,
          'subaru': 3},
 'Tom': {'benz': 3,
         'bmw': 8,
         'ford': 4,
         'german_cars': 11,
         'gmc': 2,
         'subaru': 10}}
```

Comment: When I use the first for loop method it throws an error               TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' @user1753919

Comment: it seems you are summing an int and str. try to convert the str to int using int() function.

Comment: so it will be something like this : int(v['benz'])...?@user1753919

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the outer dictionary and then modify the inner dicts directly:

```
for owner, cars in my_dictionary.items():
    cars['german_cars'] = cars.get('bmw', 0) + cars.get('benz', 0)
```

FWIW, I used [*dict.get()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) so the lookups would not fail if either "bmw" or "benz" was missing.